# python 2.7 unicode writer robust to NoneType

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I was hoping to use UnicodeWriter from [the official examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) not to hiccup on Unicode data when trying to do a CSV write. However, if I have blanks/missing/NaN in the list that should be a row, I get this error:

```
    self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is there an easy fix?

I repeat the 'official code' below:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

A previous question (though about string conversion of numbers) solved this problem too, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884299/938408).
Just add a conversion to unicode: `self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])`