# How to write text with apostrophes to csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

I parse XML with python and want to write text to *.csv* file, but if I have apostrophes in text python throws error:

> ```
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
> position 35-42: character maps to undefined
> ```

Text is in the form of: "some text 'some text' some text".

My code works well when quotation marks are inside text but with apostrophes python throws error.

When I write the same text to .txt file then everything is okei.

```
fail = open("some_file.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(fail, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=";")
...do stuff
writer.writerow(text)
```

How can I write text with apostrophes to .csv file?

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725898/how-to-handle-double-quotes-inside-field-values-with-csv-module)

Comment: @Dex'ter: It seems to be a Unicode issue, not an "escaping quotes" issue. So your duplicate is not helpful here. Question to OP: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I believe if you changed the line `writer.writerow(text)` to `writer.writerow(text.encode('utf-8'))` then you could be back in business.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884190/python-csv-unicode-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xf6-in-position-1-o

Comment: I am using python 3.5.2

Comment: I have the same issue. Any thoughts?